# How do I set form items order in a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to set my own form order in a Django form but when i run my app, every time i got a new form ordering. Here is the code :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta():
    fields =['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    model = get_user_model()
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["password1"].label = "Your Password"
    self.fields["password2"].label = "Repeat Your Password"
```

And the user model is :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, PermissionsMixin
# Create your models here.

class UserModel(User,PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
         return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

What can I do in this situation?
thanks in advance

Comment: `Class Meta` You are using `class Meta()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just do this and it works for me :

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta():
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()
        fields_order = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields["password1"].label = "Your Password"
       self.fields["password2"].label = "Repeat Your Password"
```